# Android 2.3 - Starting download message upon login

Tags: android, authentication

If I run this link `http://50.16.222.70/solvo-solutions-authorization-web/rest/authenticate?response_type=token&client_id=3bbadcd5b5131ccd8c3ba16261d1e85062e53afc36a7b280` on Android 4.0 (or on a PC web browser) and login (username joymungol.kevin@yahoo.com password aaaa), I get a `json` string on the next page as expected, but if I run the same link on Android 2.3, I get a message `"Starting download"` and download is **unsuccessful**. Is there any setting I need to change on android 2.3 browser to get this to run? Note that when clicking on login, a servlet is being accessed (login.do) and it seems that the browser is trying to download the servet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my way through. The response type from the servlet was application/json. Had to change it to text/html. Android 2.3 version browser automatically downloads application/json response types.